# JTable column header not showing

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I don't know why, but the header in the column won't display, I tried using a `JScrollPane` but it still won't work. Am I missing something?

```
Frame1.setVisible(false);
Frame2.setSize(600,600);
Frame2.setLayout(null);
Frame2.setVisible(true);

int totalItems = Integer.parseInt(numOfItems.getText());

//Jtable

String[] column = {"Item"," Weight","Value"};
String[][] data = new String[totalItems][3];
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data,column);
JTable table = new JTable(model);
table.setBounds(50,50,400,500);
table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(200,50));

JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
Frame2.add(table);
Frame2.add(scroll);
```

Here's the output:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/455QU.png)

Comment: What I usually do is call method [setAutoResizeMode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setAutoResizeMode-int-), in class `javax.swing.JTable` and set it to `AUTO_RESIZE_OFF`. Then I add the `JTable` to a `JScrollPane` (as you have done). Note that you almost never need to call method `setBounds`. Refer to [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html).

Comment: 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). 3) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, ..

Comment: .. `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently. 4) In future, please include a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: 1) Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. 2) `Frame2.add(table);` - you remove the table from the scroll pane. A component can only have a single parent. Delete that statement.